# Insert element between anchor and img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible in some way to add an element ( `<div></div>` in this case) in between the anchor tag and the image tag via javascript/jquery?
high prefer if it can be possible using the id of the img tag.

```
<a href=""><img id="123" src="..."></a>
```

to

```
<a href="#"><img id="123" src="..."><div>abc</div></a>
```

or either

```
<a href="#"><div>abc</div><img id="123" src="..."></a>
```

Comment: Can you add a class or id to the `<a>` or `<img>`

Comment: it is possible you have many option. you can use index then insert after or before

Comment: yes sorry I've forgot 1 information, i'll edit

Comment: $('a').append('<div>') . This is the simplest way.

Comment: *Is it possible in some way*, Yes. You can do `element.innerHTML = imageHTML + element.innerHTML`

Comment: Ok so ideally i can get parent of #123 and then append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append it to the parent of the image

```
var div = '<div>Some Copy</div>'
```

`$('#123').parent().append(div);`

Comment: That's worked! thanks! I was missing a callback function and that's why my parent() didn't worked; but this is the simplest correct answer I adopted!

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` method to add a child to the anchor tag.Also adding a `div` inside an `a` tag is antipattern as div is block level element & anchor tag can contain only inline element

```js
var testDiv = '<div class ="testDiv"> Test Div</div>'

$('#testAnchorTag').append(testDiv)
```

```css
.testDiv {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="testAnchorTag"><img src="..."></a>
```

For adding the `div` before the `img` you can use native js [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method

```js
var getChild = document.getElementById("childImg");
var getParent = getChild.parentNode;


var newDivChild = document.createElement('div');
newDivChild.innerHTML = "Test Div";
newDivChild.classList.add("testDiv");

getParent.insertBefore(newDivChild, getChild)
```

```css
.testDiv {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="testAnchorTag"><img id="childImg" src="..."></a>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what OP wants *in between the anchor tag and the image tag*

Comment: @Rajesh OP has already explained in 3rd line that he want that in anchor tag

Comment: @PrateikDarji Thats is why I said *not sure*.

Comment: Is it possible to get anchor from only img id? parent() seems not to work

Comment: It is possible and `parent()` is a jquery method

Comment: The problem was on loading, the a tag was not created yet, i added a callback on the function and parent() now works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) jQuery method to append and prepend any element. Here is the sample code.

```js
// to get <a href="#"><img id="123" src="..."><div>abc</div></a>
$("#123").after("<div>abc</div>");
$( "<div>abc</div>" ).insertAfter("#123");

// to get <a href="#"><div>abc</div><img id="123" src="..."></a>

$("#123").before("<div>abc</div>");
$( "<div>abc</div>" ).insertBefore( "#123" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=""><img id="123" src="..."></a>
```

Comment: That's going to put it inside of the `img` tag. If you did it on the parent `$("#123").parent().append` it would work.

Comment: I was trying this way but I continued getting this as result: 
<a href="#"><img id="123" src="..."><div>abc</div></img></a>

Comment: like Gezzasa said

Comment: @Trink check my suggestion right above your comment

Comment: parent() not take the anchor but the div over it; am i missing something?

Comment: Hi @Trink you can you before() and after() method. I have update my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can help with this. Just make sure to change the selectors once you incorporate it to your project.

---

```js
$('a').html('<div>abc</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><img id="123" src="..."></a>
```

Comment: using the `img` id :)

Comment: You can't since images are void tags with no content. They can't be a parent element.

Comment: ? the parent of the image is the `a` tag. OP wants to place the div in reference to the ID of the image.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of Vanilla JavaScript as well.

Okay, in your HTML, the `img` is inside of the `a` element i.e when you say you want another element between the `a` and `img` element what you actually mean is having that element inside of the `a` element.

Most common way to do that is to use jQuery's `.append` `.prepend` method, but some DOM API methods provided by default are capable of doing that and is supported widely across the browsers so why not go for the vanilla option.

If you reference `a` then you have to append/prepend your new HTML to it to have that new HTML around the `img` element inside, though there's an even better option, it is to use `Element.insertAdjacentHTML` - as the name suggests it can insert adjacent HTML, period.

Since you already have given your `img` element an id which is by the way incorrect, you should not start the id with a number, always use an English alphabet or an underscore, so let's say you have this:

`<a href=""><img id="_123" src="..."></a>`

All you have to do is

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('_123');
myImg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div>abc</div>');
```

In the `insertAdjacentHTML` the first argument tells where to insert that HTML, `afterend` means after the element, `beforeend` is before, similar. There are also two other options `afterbegin` and `beforebegin` which would not work on self-closing elements such as `img`, those are similar to `prepend` and `append` in nature.

More about `inserAdjacentHTML`  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML